# discord.py how to check server link

Tags: python, discord.py

i make discord bot.
How to check if a server link exists in a user message?

i write code :

```
.... skip
@bot.event
async def on_message():
    if message.content in 'https://discord.gg':
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it wrong, you should check if substring is in string, not the reverse.
Try this:

```
    if "discord.gg/" in message.content:
        message.delete()
```

I used `discord.gg/` to catch message without https.

Comment: Did it work as you want? why the triple dot?

Comment: by the way, your code is javascript, and you asked with python tag.